# Confirm function in codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript

I my application i am using ajax(Updatepanel).I am using the following code to show confirmation dialog box after finishing some update process in database. but it is not working for me.

Problem:

Confirmation box is not displaying.

code:

```
 protected void imbtnUpdate_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
 {

   // Database process     


 string javaScript = "<script language=JavaScript>\n " + "if(confirm('Do you want to update
the files?'))window.location.href = \"Upload.aspx?ID=" + ID +  
"&pt=Gm&page=Gms\"; else return false;\n" + "</script>";

 RegisterStartupScript("imbtnUpdate_Click", javaScript);
 }
```

Comment: Maybe you can explain what error you have? Any js error? no error? the script is rendering?

Comment: I am not getting any error. I want to ask confirmation. if ok redirect to upload.asp page.

Comment: you say it's "not working for you" but you don't say why it's not, so it's hard to help with that problem.  You mention confirmation: it's "ok" to redirect to any page you choose - that's a design choice, and if you want to ask about that you should probably post with a bit more of your design.

Answer (score 0):

this code is just register on the page the javascript that say... if(... bla bla bla)...

**Where is the function ?**

The RegisterStartupScript, **is not going to set on imbtnUpdateClick**, this code, and is not going to call it on Clicking the Update.

Also you must always return false, from the code I see.

**Advice**: You the view page source code, to see the generated html and see what this code do and then you understand whats the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your code behind:

```
imbtnUpdate.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return ConfirmUpdate();");
```

Then put your script into a javascript function called ConfrimUpdate()

Answer (score 0):

Are you using AJAX?

Because if your button is in an update panel, and if you are trying to add this startup script on a partial-postback you should register it by using ScriptManager.

```
 protected void imbtnUpdate_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
 {

   // Database process     


 string javaScript = "<script language=JavaScript>\n " + "if(confirm('Do you want to update
the files?'))window.location.href = \"Upload.aspx?ID=" + ID +  
"&pt=Gm&page=Gms\"; else return false;\n" + "</script>";

// RegisterStartupScript("imbtnUpdate_Click", javaScript);

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(),"imbtnUpdate_Click", javaScript , true);

 }
```

Comment: Yes i am using ajax. I have tried your code. Conform box is not getting displayed?

Comment: Well, can you try like this:

 string javaScript = "if(confirm('Do you want to update
the files?'))window.location.href = \"Upload.aspx?ID=" + ID +  
"&pt=Gm&page=Gms\"; else return false;";

Because <script> tags will be automatically by this line:

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(),"imbtnUpdate_Click", javaScript , true);

Comment: ho no. I have tried this. Not showing. I dont know where the problem is.